# How to instantiate a public tuple struct(with private field) from a different module?

Tags: struct, rust

I have a module where a tuple struct is defined as:

```
#[derive(Clone, Default, Eq, Hash, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct Id(Vec<u8>);
```

I make use of this struct in another module which needs to be imported there. But when I try to instantiate this struct `Id` as:

```
let mut id = Id(newId.as_bytes().to_vec()); //newId is a String
```

it throws an error saying:

> constructor is not visible here due to private fields

How do I make the unnamed field public (though I cannot in my case as this is part of an API)? Or is there a different way to initialize this struct ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The field `0` is private, you can either make it public like this

```
pub struct Id(pub Vec<u8>);
```

or you add an explicit constructor like this

```
impl Id {
    pub fn new(param: Vec<u8>) -> Id {
        Id(param)
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
let mut id = Id::new("newId".as_bytes().to_vec());
```

Comment: Yes @filmor, I was expecting similar thing to work but what if this definition was part of an API? Is there some other workaround?

Comment: Not in safe code, no. If the API decides that you should not have access to the value and doesn't provide a separate constructor, that's it.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to make something public to worldwide, but want to make it visible within a certain module, you can use [visibility qualifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html). Example:

```
pub struct Id(pub(crate) Vec<u8>);
```

Comment: Thanks @Masaki, good to learn this new thing. But as I told, I do not have the liberty to change the definition.